# Hide or show certain form elements based on Checkbox value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two form elements separated by table row (tr).
The first `<tr id="installCityStateZip" runat="server">` contains install address information while the second contains mailing address information `<tr id="mailCityStateZip" runat="server" runat="server">`.

There is a field name called InstallSameAsMailing, a BIT datatype in sql server database.

If install address is same as mailing address, InstallSameAsMailing has a value of 1.

If install address is not same as mailing address, the value of InstallSameAsMailing is either 0 or null.

Our requirement is that if InstallSameAsMailing = true (the value is 1) then hide everything under `<tr id="mailCityStateZip" runat="server" runat="server">` and show everything under `<tr id="installCityStateZip" runat="server">`.

The code below is not working for me. When I run it, it is not hiding `<tr id="mailCityStateZip" runat="server" runat="server">` and everything inside it.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

'//Markup

```
   <tr id="installCityStateZip" runat="server">
      <td><asp:DropDownList ID="city" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cityChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" /></td>
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="state" runat="server" Text="WI" ReadOnly="true" /></td>
      <td><asp:DropDownList ID="zip"  AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"><asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="" /></asp:DropDownList></td>
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="AccountNo" runat="server" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="mailCityStateZip" runat="server">
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="mailCity" runat="server" /></td>
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="mailState" runat="server" /></td>
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="mailZip" runat="server" /></td>
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="AccountNumber" runat="server" /></td>
  </tr>
```

'//VB

```
                Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(conString)
                Dim sqlStatement As String = "Select * FROM Addresses Where AUTOID=@addressid"
                myConnection.Open()

                Dim sqlCmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlStatement, myConnection)
                sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@addressid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = addressID
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader()

                If reader.Read() Then
                    streetAddress.Text = reader("InstallAddress").ToString()
                    city.Text = reader("InstallCity").ToString()
                    state.Text = reader("InstallState").ToString()
                    If zip.Items.FindByText(reader.ToString()) IsNot Nothing Then
                        zip.Text = reader("InstallZip").ToString()
                    End If
                    yearBuilt.Text = reader("YearBuilt").ToString()
                    waterAccountNo.Text = reader("WaterAcctNo").ToString()
                    Dim sameAddress As Boolean = reader("InstallSameAsMailing").ToString()
                    If sameAddress = True Then
                        installCityStateZip.Visible = True
                        mailCityStateZip.Visible = True
                    Else
                        installCityStateZip.Visible = True
                        mailCityStateZip.Visible = False
                    End If

                End If
```

**UPDATE:** The following code seems to be working:

```
  If reader("InstallSameAsMailing").Value.ToString() = "Yes" Then
         installCityStateZip.Visible = True
         mailCityStateZip.Visible = True
         IsInstallation.Checked = True
         IsMailing.Checked = True
  Else
         installCityStateZip.Visible = True
         mailCityStateZip.Visible = False
         IsInstallation.Checked = True
         IsMailing.Checked = False
  End If
```

Notice the two form fields added, IsInstallation and IsMailing.

If it is install is same as mailing, check both the IsInstallation and IsMailing checkboxes.

Otherwise, check the IsInstallation checkbox only.

So, our tests consistently show that whether whether or not install address is same as mailing address, only the IsInstall checkbox is checked.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Yes,  you had  If zip.Items.FindByText(reader.ToString()) IsNot Nothing Then -- converting a reader.ToString without some field/colum not going to work.

Comment: Hi Albert, always thrilled to hear from you  sir.

Are you saying the reason `IsInstallation.Checked` is getting checked but `IsMailing.checked` is not when install address is same as mailing address is because of that zipcode IF statement?

Comment: No, you had this code:  .FindByText(reader.ToString())   I mean, reader.ToString() is a bug and means nothing of value. however, reader("SomeColum").ToString() is valid. So, that line of code did not make sense, and can't work. As you follow up code shows, you not using that "bug" expression anymore.

Comment: I think these lines of code... Dim sameAddress As Boolean = reader("InstallSameAsMailing").ToString()
                    If sameAddress = True Then... Should be.... Dim sameAddress As Integer = reader("InstallSameAsMailing").ToString()
                    If sameAddress > 0 True Then...

Comment: @Zeddy, thank you for your help. When I try your suggestion, neither boxes get checked. However, with the Boolean usage, if sameAddress is true both installation and mailing checkboxes get checked. If sameAddress is not true, none of the boxes get checked. So, it is a bit frustrating especially on the surface, this is supposed to be very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this worked perfectly for me. I hope it helps someone else some day.

```
    If Not reader("InstallSameAsMailing") Is DBNull.Value AndAlso Convert.ToBoolean(reader("InstallSameAsMailing")) Then
        IsInstallation.Visible = True
        installation.Checked = True
        mailCityStateZip.Visible = False
        IsMailing.Checked = True
    Else
        installCityStateZip.Visible = True
        IsInstallation.Checked = True
        mailCityStateZip.Visible = False
        IsMailing.Checked = False
    End If
```